# Elastisearch multi match search not working properly

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an user in elasticsearch full_name of user is Mike John Khosa and username is mikekhosa. So when I search user khosa then this user should come into search result but current not searched in my current case. Below is my working code

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 40,
  "sort": [
    {
      "username.raw": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "uid",
    "username",
    "full_name",
    "picture",
    "bucket"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "user"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "db_id": 27428
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
              "query": "khosa",
              "type": "cross_fields",
              "fields": [
                "username.raw",
                "username",
                "full_name.raw",
                "full_name"
              ]
            }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "terms": {
          "id": [
            "u-2",
            "u-19712"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have search on google more than 5 hours but failed to implement good solution. I don't know that where i am doing mistake

Comment: What does your mapping look like? What are some example records to use?

Comment: Which Analyzer did you use in the mapping for the full_name field. Case sensitivity is dependent on the analyzer.

Comment: @Tim here is my username mapping
" "username": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "analyzer": "autocomplete"
              }"